# Air for IOS Webview - apple app review says every tab and/or button launches mobile Safari.?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, webview, safari, air

I pulling my hair out trying to figure out where I have gone wrong.

I created a very simple app for ios that uses webView to load certain webpages within app.   from my knowledge and every ios air webView reference I have found online I have coded everything correctly.  Runs beautifully on android.

apple app review says every tab and/or button launches mobile Safari.?

I don't see how this is possible because they even said my button that only has gotoAndPlay(2);  apparently that navigates to Safari also.  ?

here's the code I used for webView:

```
QMBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, QMB);
function QMB(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 135, stage.stageWidth, 600 ); 
    webView.stage = this.stage;
    webView.loadURL( "http://mywebpageeurl.com.au" );
    whiteBOX.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

and this is the code for my internal frame nav.

```
Menu_BTN2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GoMenuSRC);
function GoMenuSRC(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    webView.stage = null;  
    whiteBOX.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Am I missing something or ????

The only other thing I could think could be the culprit might be my error handler to handle errors when I click tel: or mailto: links on my webpages.

The code for the tel: / mailto: error handling.

```
// Error handle
var openLinksInDefaultBrowser = false;

//Check tel: func
function cdCTfunc():void
{
      var NEWtelLNK = webView.location.substr(0,4);
      if (NEWtelLNK=='tel:')
            {
                openLinksInDefaultBrowser = true;
            }else{openLinksInDefaultBrowser = false;}
}

webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, function     (ev:LocationChangeEvent):void
  {
    cdCTfunc();
    if(openLinksInDefaultBrowser == false) 
          {
              ev.preventDefault();
              webView.loadURL(ev.location); //'ev.url' changed to 'ev.location'started with prerelease build - [07/20/10]
           } 
    if (openLinksInDefaultBrowser == true)
          {
               trace('page loaded in default browser');
                var phStr:String=ev.location;
                var callPH:URLRequest= new URLRequest(phStr);
                navigateToURL(callPH);
           }        
    });


webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, function (ev:LocationChangeEvent):void
{
    if (webView.location.indexOf('authentication_complete') != -1)
            {
                trace('auth token is: ' +           webView.location.substr(webView.location.indexOf('token=') + 6));

            }
    trace('the new location is: ' + webView.location);
    trace(webView.location.substr(0,4));

});

webView.addEventListener('complete', function(ev:Event):void
{
      trace('complete event');
});

webView.addEventListener('error', function(ev:ErrorEvent):void
{   
      var phStr:String=webView.location;
      var callPH:URLRequest= new URLRequest(phStr);
      navigateToURL(callPH);
      webView.isHistoryBackEnabled;
      webView.historyBack();
      trace('SOME Bloody Error Loading The Page: ' + ev.text);
      trace(openLinksInDefaultBrowser);
  });
```

but I still don't see how this could cause a gotoAndStop(); to launch safari.

I am absolutely stumped.

Please Help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by iOS air? Is all that your app does is display web pages and nothing else? If so then your app will be rejected for that reason, apps that don't do anything or very little else except just show web pages are not permitted. Them mentioning Safari might just be the reviewer's way of saying as such.

Comment: app is developed in Adobe Animate using Air for IOS 21 sdk.   App doesn't just display a webpage.  It has multiple functionality that utilizes webView. to display certain search results and so on.   Apple have been very direct in the past in rejecting my basic webView apps, however in this case reviewer understands fully the desired app functionality and has replied with and I quote. "It would be appropriate to provide the intended content to the users within the app.
We are looking forward to reviewing your app once these issues are resolved."

Comment: and before that they said   "what we encounter with the current submitted binary is that every tab and/or button launches mobile Safari. This includes the different colored magnifying glass buttons next to the different search fields, the map and magnifying glass icon in the lower banner menu, and all the tabs in the Main Menu that we view by tapping on the top left menu button. "

Comment: And as I said before 3 of the button functions mentioned only have gotoAndPlay(); within them?

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting your app for review you should run it through Testflight.

This allows you to test an 'AppStore' build of your binary so you will see exactly what the reviewer will see.

http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=7608